# Mergesort: what's up with the last step in the merge operation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

The following mergesort is from *Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis* (Weiss). What I'm wondering about is the last `for` loop on the merge step. I understand that we have to copy `tmpArray` back into `array`, but I don't understand why we do it from `rightend`, and why we don't have `i` go from `0` to `tmpArray.size`. Can someone explain please?

```
public static void mergeSort( Comparable [ ] a )
{
  Comparable [ ] tmpArray = new Comparable[ a.length ];
  mergesort( a, tmpArray, 0, a.length - 1 );
}

public static void mergesort( Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmpArray,
int left, int right )
{
  if( left < right ) {
    int center = ( left + right ) / 2;
    mergesort( a, tmpArray, left, center );
    mergesort( a, tmpArray, center + 1, right );
    merge( a, tmpArray, left, center + 1, right );
  }
}

public static void merge( Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmpArray,
int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd )
{

  int leftEnd = rightPos - 1;
  int tmpPos = leftPos;
  int numElements = rightEnd - leftPos + 1;

  while( leftPos <= leftEnd && rightPos <= rightEnd )
    if( a[ leftPos ].compareTo( a[ rightPos ] ) <= 0 )
      tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ leftPos++ ];
    else
      tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ rightPos++ ];

  while( leftPos <= leftEnd ) // Copy rest of first half
    tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ leftPos++ ];

  while( rightPos <= rightEnd ) // Copy rest of right half
    tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ rightPos++ ];

  for( int i = 0; i < numElements; i++, rightEnd-- )
    a[ rightEnd ] = tmpArray[ rightEnd ]; // Copy tmpArray back
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main reason to do things this way is because the value of `rightPos`, the spot where the subarray starts, has been destructively modified by the inner loop (note the use of `rightPos++`.  Consequently, in order to write the value back properly, the last loop counts backwards down to where `rightPos` originally was.  Were it to just start at `rightPos` and count forward, it would be writing to the wrong index.

That said, I don't see any reason to do it this way.  It would be easier to just declare new variables and modify those values instead of destroying the inputs and doing extra gymnastics to recover the original values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And can we just say `tmpArray.size` instead of `numElements`?

Comment: No, these values are different.  `tmpArray.size` is the size of the entire input array (notice how it's initially sized in the top-level mergesort call).  `numElements` is the number of elements in this particular slice of the array.

Comment: Also counting down from n-1 to 0 is sometimes faster than counting up from 0 to n-1.  But people rarely concern themselves with such things anymore.

Comment: Note that not all mergesort implementations have that final loop in the merge callable - perhaps especially if using linked lists.  Also, timsort, which is basically a highly optimized mergesort, manages to do merging in place, stably, by using a merge_high and a merge_low - this is using a Python list, which is more or less a resizeable, potentially heterogeneous array.